# java.sql.SQLException:[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near “ID”:syntax error)

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, user-interface, sql-insert

I am trying to insert the following data, but when I press the save button the following error is displayed: java.sql.SQLException:[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near “ID”:syntax error)

Thanks for the help=)

```
JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
    btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                String query="INSERT INTO PatientInfo (Patient ID, First Name, Last Name, Date of Birth, Address, Emergency Phone Number, Medical Condition, Appointments, Milling, Comments) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                preparedstatement=connection.prepareStatement(query);
                preparedstatement.setString(1, patientIDtextField.getText());
                preparedstatement.setString(2, firstNametextField.getText());
                preparedstatement.setString(3, lastNametextField.getText());
                preparedstatement.setString(4, dobtextField.getText());
                preparedstatement.setString(5, addresstextField.getText());
                preparedstatement.setString(6, EPNtextField.getText());
                preparedstatement.setString(7, MedicalContextField.getText());
                preparedstatement.setString(8,ApptextField.getText());
                preparedstatement.setString(9, BillingtextField.getText());
                preparedstatement.setString(10, CommentstextField.getText());

                preparedstatement.executeQuery();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Saved");


            } catch (Exception e1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1);
            }
            finally{
                try{
                    preparedstatement.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e1){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You need to quote column names with space with `"` so `"Patient ID"` and so on. Space is illegal without explicit quoting with identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

You have a space here `Patient ID` and in the other column names too. That's the problem. If your column names **really contain spaces** you should qualify them somehow: with `"` for example. So you should try `"Patient ID"` instead.